# Eclipse neon not resolving maven dependencies as jars but as classes

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-neon

I have been chasing this problem for several days.  I have recently upgraded to Eclipse neon from luna.  I have multiple projects that have dependencies on jars defined in other projects in the same development space.  I define the project dependencies solely in the pom.xml and everything has worked great.  However, I have one project that has 2 dependent projects and one project resolves itself as a jar and the other resolves itself as a reference to the path of the generated classes in the other project.

Here is the snippet of the pom.xml that refers to the other projects:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ihc.hdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>LeopardSearchBase</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ihc.hdd.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>IndexerBase</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image: When I build the project the references in the maven dependencies of the project are:]

Notice the 'IndexerBase' project is referenced by the class path and 'LeopardSearchBase' is referenced by the jar.
These project are defined as jars and as far as I can tell are configured in exactly the same way.

The odd thing is that using Eclipse luna, running 'maven->Update Project...' it configures itself correctly, but pointing Eclipse neon to the same project, it configures itself incorrectly.

[image: The project dependency references from Eclipse luna]

org.eclipse.wst.common.component from Eclipse luna looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
  <wb-module deploy-name="EddConsole-1.0">
        <dependent-module archiveName="IndexerBase-1.1.0.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/IndexerBase/IndexerBase">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="LeopardSearchBase-1.3.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/LeopardSearchBase/LeopardSearchBase">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
    <property name="context-root" value="EddConsole"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="src/main/webapp"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/target/classes"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/java"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
  </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

And org.eclipse.wst.common.component from Eclipse neon looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
  <wb-module deploy-name="EddConsole-1.0">
        <dependent-module archiveName="LeopardSearchBase-1.3.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/LeopardSearchBase/LeopardSearchBase">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
    <property name="context-root" value="EddConsole"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="src/main/webapp"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/target/classes"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/java"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
  </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

I am hoping I've just missed a configuration option here.  With the project running the way it is, it will not properly deploy as a web app.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Right click on the project -> Properties -> Maven -> uncheck `Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects` .?

Comment: I tried that before sending this question.  Didn't work.  All that does is turn off all linkage to those projects.

Comment: This behavior doesn't exhibit itself in older versions of Eclipse.  I was previously using Luna (4.4.2) and everything worked correctly.